# SQLAlchemy intersect error

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

`user1 = User(username='john')`

`user2 = User(username='jim')`

`user1.intersect(user2).all()` throws an error when using MariaDB, but not with SQLite.

Here's the error:

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERSECT SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.email ' at line 4") [SQL: 'SELECT anon_1.user_id AS anon_1_user_id, anon_1.user_username AS anon_1_user_username, anon_1.user_email AS anon_1_user_email, anon_1.user_password AS anon_1_user_password, anon_1.user_first_name AS anon_1_user_first_name, anon_1.user_last_name AS anon_1_user_last_name, anon_1.user_about_me AS anon_1_user_about_me, anon_1.user_last_seen AS anon_1_user_last_seen, anon_1.user_member_since AS anon_1_user_member_since, anon_1.user_last_message_read_time AS anon_1_user_last_message_read_time, anon_1.user_last_request_read_time AS anon_1_user_last_request_read_time \nFROM (SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.email AS user_email, user.password AS user_password, user.first_name AS user_first_name, user.last_name AS user_last_name, user.about_me AS user_about_me, user.last_seen AS user_last_seen, user.member_since AS user_member_since, user.last_message_read_time AS user_last_message_read_time, user.last_request_read_time AS user_last_request_read_time \nFROM user, friendships \nWHERE friendships.user_id = %s AND friendships.friend_id = user.id INTERSECT SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.email AS user_email, user.password AS user_password, user.first_name AS user_first_name, user.last_name AS user_last_name, user.about_me AS user_about_me, user.last_seen AS user_last_seen, user.member_since AS user_member_since, user.last_message_read_time AS user_last_message_read_time, user.last_request_read_time AS user_last_request_read_time \nFROM user, friendships \nWHERE friendships.user_id = %s AND friendships.friend_id = user.id) AS anon_1'] [parameters: (1, 2)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support INTERSECT. Sqlite does. MariaDB does as of [version 10.3](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/intersect/).

Comment: Intersect can be thought of as a "special case" of a (natural) self join on all columns (or just the key columns).